# Using a likelihood function in pymcmcstat

Tags: python, parameters, statistics, bayesian

I'm trying to use pymcmcstat to estimate some parameters, but I am not sure how to match the sum of squares function to my problem. I calculated a log likelihood of two lognormal distributions I have, and want to use this in my model. What I have now is:

```
from pymcmcstat.MCMC import MCMC

mcstat = MCMC()  #initialise mcmc
x = t
y = I*100000
mcstat.data.add_data_set(x,y) #create data using prevalence
def ssfun(q, data): #supposed to be a function, sum of sqs or log ???
    m, b = q # slope and offset
    x = data.xdata[0]
    y = data.ydata[0]
    # Evaluate model
    ymodel = m*x + b
    res = ymodel - y
    return (res ** 2).sum(axis=0)

mcstat.model_settings.define_model_settings(sos_function=ssfun) # put function into model
mcstat.simulation_options.define_simulation_options(nsimu=10.0e3) #number of sims to run
mcstat.parameters.add_model_parameter(name='beta', theta0=8, minimum = 0, maximum = 20) #priors
mcstat.parameters.add_model_parameter(name='gamma',theta0=0.4, minimum = 0, maximum=2) #priors
mcstat.run_simulation() #run mcmc
```

where `t` and `I` are arrays of length 500 each containing data values (time and corresponding population numbers)

I am receiving the errors

```
  File "<ipython-input-36-b8790f50839a>", line 2, in ssfun
    m, b = q # slope and offset

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Which I assume is because my sum of squared function is not correct. What I don't understand is how I would utilise my loglikelihood or likelihood function in this problem?

----EDIT-------

The log likelihood I constructed, by adding the logs of the two lognormal prob density functions I had:

```
muPrev, sigmaPrev = 400, 40 #I
muInc, sigmaInc = 300, 30 #cInc
n = 10000

# logPrev = np.random.lognormal(np.log((muPrev**2) / (muPrev**2 + sigmaPrev**2)**0.5), (np.log(1 + (sigmaPrev**2 / muPrev**2)))**0.5, n) #lognormal
# logInc = np.random.lognormal(np.log((muInc**2) / (muInc**2 + sigmaInc**2)**0.5), (np.log(1 + (sigmaInc**2 / muInc**2)))**0.5, n) #lognormal

xPrev = 400 #value of x in formula for log of pdf
xInc = 300

logmuPrev = np.log((muPrev**2) / (muPrev**2 + sigmaPrev**2)**0.5) #lognormal params
logsdPrev = (np.log(1 + (sigmaPrev**2 / muPrev**2)))**0.5

logmuInc = np.log((muInc**2) / (muInc**2 + sigmaInc**2)**0.5)#lognormal params
logsdInc = (np.log(1 + (sigmaInc**2 / muInc**2)))**0.5

L_prev = -0.5*((np.log(400) - logmuPrev) / logsdPrev)**2 - np.log(400* logsdPrev * (2*math.pi)**0.5) #log of pdf for prev and inc
L_inc = -0.5*((np.log(300) - logmuInc) / logsdInc)**2 - np.log(300* logsdInc * (2*math.pi)**0.5)

logsum = L_prev + L_inc #summing logs
np.exp(logsum) #exp for likelihood
```

Comment: Why did you expect that `q` consists of two values?

Comment: I know it's incorrect, what I'm trying to find out is how to reshape it so that it can fit my problem. Please see the edit for an example of my log likelihood